# Dropbox integration in swift

Tags: iphone, swift, dropbox

I am creating an application to integrate DropBox picker. For this i am using objective c framework. For this I am following this [link](https://blogs.dropbox.com/developers/2014/09/swift-apps-with-dropbox/) But I am getting an error showing 'Dropbox/Dropbox.h' file not found. I searched a lot about this error but every body saying that the bridging header is not correct. But I am using FMDB also in this bridging header file its working properly and its not the mistake of bridging header. Some body please help me to find out a solution for this. When I try to create new application with the same flow then there is no error.

```
//#import <Dropbox/Dropbox.h>


#import "FMDatabase.h"

#import "FMDatabaseAdditions.h"

#import "FMDatabasePool.h"

#import "FMDatabaseQueue.h"

#import "FMResultSet.h"
```

This is my bridging header without dropbox , in this FMDB is working, so I assume that its not the mistake of bridging header.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem. I think they may have changed the name and failed to update their documentation.  Looking inside the DropboxSDK.Framework, there is no Dropbox.h file but there is a DropboxSDK.h  So if instead you use

```
#import <DropboxSDK/DropboxSDK.h>
```

Then you may find that it works.  At least, my compiler errors go away!

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But I am using Dropbox.framework and there is Dropbox.h file in the framework.